# universal Detector encoding in golang?

Tags: go, utf-8

there are some sample code `http.DetectContentType(buffer[:n])` detect for limited charset , in case like ANSSI it recognize as UTF-8

is any universal solution for this problem?

Comment: if your goal is to check that byte array is UTF8 string, then you can use [utf8.valid](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#Valid)

Comment: thank you so much @VladyslavMunin, it solved my problem

Comment: will post it as separate answer, maybe someone else can find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

to check that byte array is UTF8 string, you can use [utf8.valid](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#Valid)